# Mac OSX screencast solutions

Tags: macos, screencasts

I need to make some quick and simple demo videos of a web application. These videos will need to be embedded into help pages in the application, but can be externally hosted.

As a startup without lots of funds, my preference is to find open source, free, or inexpensive solutions. However, if there are really excellent solutions that cost more, I'd like to know about them for future reference.

I've seen some websites that claim to do this, but am not sure if they would be suitable for my needs. Any experience with services like [screentoaster.com](http://www.screentoaster.com/) or [screenjelly.com](http://www.screenjelly.com/)?

What software solutions are there?  I'd like to do this on my snow leopard MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quicktime X, built in Snow Leopard is a convenient tool to produce screencasts !

You're running 10.6 so it's free for you. I guess it won't be hard to record them locally and later integer the videos into the pages with a web based video player (that's what i did) !

[image]

I've used it to make basics howtos for my students.

Comment: Sweet, very cool! I'll check it out. I'm Hopeful it will do those zoom in and focus features, not just constantly full screen, but if not I can live without that.

Comment: Yes you can zoom in/out where you want and also gain viewer attention on some points !