# What program can I use to make animated videos with Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, video, video-editing

I've seen a lot of these cool info-diagram style voice-over videos like this one for Google Plus One:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAyUNI3_V2c&feature=player_embedded

**What types of tools are required to make something like that?**

Edit:

Here are a few more examples of the types of videos I am wondering about creating:

[http://www.lemonadeandmint.com/reels/](http://referer.us/http://www.lemonadeandmint.com/reels/)

Comment: Jing is for OS X too, try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do something like the google's video you posted you will definitely need something like After Effects or other more powerful video editor and some patience to get things done.

To create a simple screencast video you should check this SU question:

[Mac OSX screencast solutions](https://superuser.com/questions/106434/mac-osx-screencast-solutions)

Comment: Nice. After Effects looks like what I want to use if I want to create the animated portion. Is it the industry standard or are there any similar tools?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is the industry standard, specially being a part of Adobe CS5 studio pack